# Raspberry Pi opencv 3 and node-opencv

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I successfully compiled opencv 3 on my raspberry pi raspbian system. Now i am trying since ages to get node-opencv to install but with not much success.

Here is the error output from npm

```
npm install -g opencv


|

opencv@1.0.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv
node-gyp rebuild
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
In file included from ../src/init.cc:5:0:
../src/CascadeClassifierWrap.h:5:3: error: ‘CascadeClassifier’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
In file included from ../src/init.cc:6:0:
../src/VideoCaptureWrap.h:5:7: error: ‘VideoCapture’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type
opencv.target.mk:99: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.12.28+
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! opencv@1.0.0 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv@1.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the opencv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls opencv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.12.28+
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "opencv"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local/include/opencv
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I really am out of ideas and would much apprichiate some major help here.

Thanks a lot
best regards Thomas

Comment: No body any clue to help out? I would realy appreciate some help a lot. I have no clue what to do anymore.

Comment: Identical errors on MacOSX 10.10.  I'm wondering if the node opencv package only works with OpenCV 2.x...

Comment: Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: No. But I see that it's been posted as a question on the node opencv project (https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/191).

Answer (score 0):

node-opencv does not fully support OpenCV 3.x yet. They mention it on the readme [here](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv). You should be able to install 2.4 on your RPi2 with this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/), or search that same site if you have an RPi3.